# How to show the Small Pointer in WPF DataGrid as in WinForms DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am working on WPF and DataGrids, I am really new on this. **And I need the WPF DataGrid to show in its row headers the small pointer** as in the WindowsForms DataGridView does (it looks like a small triangle pointing to right).

I have tried with this property:

```
dataGrid1.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.All;
```

But doing as above the dataGrid got some very small headers which seems to be just to select the entire row.

I have done some research about it but I have found nothing.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I have found two links which allow me to do what I was trying to accomplish:

[WPF DataGrid Row indicators](http://thedovgals.com/andre/blog/?tag=wpf-datagrid-row-indicators)

or this one:

[Changing the style of the selected row of the DataGrid control](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Changing-the-style-of-the-selected-row-of-the-DataGrid-control.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

2 things --

1) specify a SortMemberPath -- this will get you the default style 2) style the grid's header template